# Tableview after tableview

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, cell

I need to create two tableviews, a 'parent' and a 'child'. In the 'parent' tableview, the user can create a cell, give it a name, and upon clicking this cell, a second 'child' tableview will be displayed. In the 'child' tableview, the user should also be able to add unique cells to the cell that was tapped. For example, the user is presented with a table view. The user taps the + sign to add a cell, and then names it. The user taps Done and the first tableview appears again with the new named cell in it. The user taps the cell and then creates a cell that is unique to the cell above it. Using Core Data, how can I achieve this? I know how to create a simple tableview, but the part I'm having problems with is having the created cells in the second view controller be unique to where they were created.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by, "The user taps the cell and then creates a cell that is unique to the cell above it" Can you elaborate?

Comment: On the first table view, the user taps a cell and is sent to a new table view. In this tableview, the user can add new cells. These cells should be unique to that tableview (they should not be displayed if you tap any other row in the first tableview).

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now, but it would help to know what kind of data you want to display in these cells. A more concrete example of what would be displayed in a cell in the first table, and how the data in the new cells in the second table relate to to the cell's data in the first table would be helpful.

Comment: The first table displays a list of routine objects, from which only the name will be displayed. Each routine object has its own unique array of tasks. The tasks of each routine object are displayed in the second table.

Comment: You would create a second entity type to represent the rows in the second table view (the child entity) and then set a one to many relationship between the parent and the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create at least 2 entities in your core data model. I'll call the first entity Routine objects based on your comment. The Routine objects would have a relationship called "Tasks" with a destination to a Task entity. This would be a to-many relationship, so each Routine object could have many Tasks. When you select a cell, you would pass the managed object represented in that cell to the second table view controller so you can add Task objects to that specific entity.

Comment: Considering that the Task objects would have to be an NSSet so that they can be stored, how would you do it so that the cells are in order of creation (NSSet is an unordered collection type)?

Comment: @rodrigochousal, you would probably have to add a date created attribute to the Task entity, and sort based on that.